# Is there a way to say collection[attr1=value].attr2=value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, iterator

Is there a way to say something like

```
User.friends[id=1].posts=data
```

in Javascript, where User.friends is a collection of Friend items, one of whose properties is 'id'?

I am iterating over a collection User.friends, which is a collection of Friend objects that have 3 properties (id, posts, and likes). The inner iterator instance variable, friend, seems passed-by-value not by-reference; so, how do I elegantly set the parent object's properties from within the iterator?

```
    async.each(User.friends, function(friend, cb) {
            var url="https://graph.facebook.com/"+friend.id.id+"/?fields=posts&since="+ moment(postFromDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + '&access_token=' + User.accessToken;
            request.get({
                url: url,
                json: true
                }, function (error, response, body) {
                    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                        console.log(body);
                        //I WANT TO SET THE ACTUAL User.friend[i].posts value, 
                        //but I do not know how to get the value of 'i'?
                        friend.posts=body.data; //this just sets local friend var                           
                        cb(null); 
                    } else {
                        console.log(error);
                        throw error;
                    }

            });  //...request.get
            }, function(error, result) {
                callback();
        }); //...async_each
```

Sorry if this is a dumb question. Any help really appreciated. I've tried:

```
_.findWhere(User.friends,{id: friend.id}).posts=body.data;
```

but this doesn't seem to work (I think it just sets a local value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `filter` method:

```
var result = User.friends.filter(function(item) { return item.id === 1; })[0].posts = data;
```

Comment: That seems to return a copy of the object - but if I set result.post, the collection User.friends is unaffected. Is there a way to get the index of matched attributes so I can set the collection directly? e.g. User.friend[i].post=xxx where i equals the index of User.friends[id=1]

Comment: No, it returns an array in which the actual object is stored. I just forgot the `[0]` the first time. But as it is right now, you should be able to manipulate your actual object. See this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wRV3L/  And you can get the index by wrapping this function in `User.friends.indexOf()` but maybe there is a better way for getting the index...I'm not sure

Comment: My humble apologies - it was a bug on the right-side assignment. This method works great! Thank you!

Comment: No need for apologies. As I said, the first version of my answer was in fact errorous and I had to correct it later. But I'm glad it helped you now :)